# Automatically import to a staging environment in SF NPSP once file is dropped in SFTP

Tags: data, automation, import, npsp, sftp

Our nonprofit organization is currently running on a custom developed CRM, but implementing Salesforce NPSP.

The current business process is

1. A donor file is loaded to our SFTP from a telemarketing vendor (currently XML but can be CSV).
2. The file is automatically brought into a staging environment on the CRM, where it is cleansed and appended based on business logic before fully being pushed through into CRM.
3. Any data that is not pushed through, will be manually cleansed and updated as needed (by a human).

Is it possible to replicate this in SF NPSP?
Once a file is dropped in SFTP, we need to automatically import to a staging table where the file is cleansed and appended.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Salesforce can't interact with SFTP out-of-the-box, so you would need use a 3rd party SFTP and automation tools.  Regarding the NPSP Data Import process, be sure to read the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sfdo.NPSP_Import_Data.htm&type=5).